# How to add storyboard named 'main_ipad'

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, storyboard

My app runs on my iPhone 6+ ok.
I want to run it on an iPad mini 4, but I get the error below.
However, Project > General > Deployment Info > Devices = Universal.

How do I add storyboard named 'Main_iPad'?

```
2016-10-25 20:01:17.602324 AsMan x4[314:12445] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Could not find a storyboard named 'Main_iPad' in bundle NSBundle </var/containers/Bundle/Application/9F12175F-0A54-42A5-9984-6565803E5E45/AsMan x4.app> (loaded)'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1913381c0 0x18fd7055c 0x197932bd0 0x197403b48 0x1971ec0a8 0x1974027c0 0x197417080 0x1973ff8c4 0x192ed98bc 0x192ed9728 0x192ed9ad0 0x1912e6278 0x1912e5bc0 0x1912e37c0 0x191212048 0x1971e55dc 0x1971e0360 0x1000b2eac 0x1901f45b8)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: just add it as a new file? But i dont think you need this if you dont have the storyboard for ipad exclusive key in your .plist

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps to create new storyboard named: `Main_iPad`

```
NewFile --> Storyboard(UserInterface) --> SaveAs:Main_iPad --> create
```

---

[image]

[image]